# Map multiple paths to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a controller called CardController. Currently I have routes like card_path that map to /cards/:id. I would like to make it so that I can use /trips/:id and /events/:id that map to the same /cards/:id. I know I'll have to override card_path eventually but is it possible to set up my routes file for this? Do I need to set up a Trip and Event controller that just redirect to the card actions?

Edit:

Trips should completely map to cards, meaning 'trips/1/edit' should end up at 'cards/1/edit', 'trips/1/images/12' should end up at 'cards/1/images/12'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding some controller to the routes file.

routes.rb

```rb
def card_routes
  member do
    get 'test'
  end
end

class TripsController < CardsController; end

resources :trips { card_routes }
resources :cards { card_routes }
```

Now `/trips/1/test` and `/cards/1/test` go to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do something like:

```
get 'trips/:id' => 'cards#show'
```

Try accessing different trips in your browser, `trips/1` or `trips/2` (if cards with those ids exist), and they should redirect to the appropriate card.

If you haven't already, I recommend taking a few minutes and reading the Routing Guide, as it's really comprehensive and shows different ways of accomplishing things:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I realize that but I want everything in cards to map to trips, so 'trips/:id/edit' => 'cards#edit' along with embedded resources.

Comment: I would go with @TK-421 suggestion as described in [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)      ` resources :cards resource: trips, to: redirect('/cards') `